# Как поправить массив чтобы он вывел все чисто

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, имена, удаление-символов

```
//dz 4
void Normalize(string[] array) {
    array.Trim(' ', '!')
};

string[] names = {
   "  naomi scott !", "  tom --", " sarah jessica parker", "Mike Meyers",
    "Anna sofia rob", " tony fargo ", "Lily Collinz", " Angelina joli ",
   "Nataly Portman ", " john smith  "
};

Normalize(names);

Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", names)}]");
```

Нужно чтобы вывелось так

```
["Naomi Scott", "Tom", "Sarah Jessica Parker", "Mike Meyers",
"Anna Sofia Rob", "Tony Fargo", "Lily Collinz", "Angelina Joli",
"Nataly Portman", "John Smith"]
```

Comment: переформулируй вопрос. Как выводится сейчас и как нужно что бы выводилось. Пока что вопрос непонятен

Comment: @Andrew он просто задублировал блок текста. Я поправил, должно стать понятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [String.Trim(char[])](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0#system-string-trim(system-char())). В этом случае будут удалены все символы, переданные массивом.
Для "капитализации" имён можно воспользоваться методом [TextInfo.ToTitleCase(String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=net-6.0):

```cs
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
char[] dirtyChars = new char[]{ ',', ' ', '-', '!' };
string[] dirtyNames = new string[] {
    "  naomi scott !",
    "  tom --",
    " sarah jessica parker",
    "Mike Meyers",
    "Anna sofia rob",
    " tony fargo ",
    "Lily Collinz",
    " Angelina joli ",
    "Nataly Portman ",
    " john smith  "
};
string[] names = dirtyNames
    .Select(name =>
        textInfo.ToTitleCase(name.Trim(dirtyChars))
    );

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", names));
```

P.S.: предполагаю, что автору необходимо работать с именами и если это так, то обращу внимание на необходимость дополнительной обработки [приставок](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1161216) (McDonnalds, O'Hara, d'Artagnan, von, ger, van, de).

Comment: @return поправил код. Автор не описал вопрос, а при беглом взгляде не заметил "капитализацию" имён.

Answer (score 0):

Через LINQ:

```cs
names
    .Select(name => name.Trim(' ', '!'))
    .Select(name => name
        .Split()
        .Select(word => char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1))
        .Aggregate((acc, word) => acc + " " + word))
    .ToArray()
```